# Juniper route leak from VRF to global RT using rib-groups

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

I'm trying to export routes from *VRF.inet.0* to *inet.0* using rib-groups. Routes are placed into VRF.inet.0 from another PE by MP-BGP (family inet-vpn) session. That's rib group configuration:

```
rib-groups {
  VRF-GRT {
    export-rib VRF.inet.0;
    import-rib [ VRF.inet.0 inet.0 ];
  }
}
```

Then I apply rib-group into routing-instances protocols bgp configuration:

```
VRF {
    instance-type vrf;
    interface em0.0;
    route-distinguisher 200:99;
    vrf-target target:200:99;
    vrf-table-label;
    protocols {
        bgp {
            family inet {
                unicast {
                    rib-group VRF-GRT;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not work for me. I have no VRF routes into inet.0. Is that a right way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not possible using rib-groups - if you're receiving the routes from another PE, then the NRLI will be carried as type `inet-vpn` instead of `inet-unicast` which you need in order to be installed in `inet.0` (even though they are ultimately installed as `inet-unicast` in the `VRF.inet.0`).

To achieve the same functionality, you might need to come at it from a different angle:

- On the far-end PE (the one that learnt the route in the first place) leak the route (using rib-groups) into inet.0 on the far-end PE.
- Make sure your BGP link from the far-end PE and the near-end PE is configured for both `inet-vpn` and `inet-unicast` - this will carry the route from the far-end PE to the near-end PE and it will be installed into inet.0
- Allow next-hop resolution for inet.0 to consult your VRF as well:

`set routing-options resolution rib inet.0 resolution-ribs  [ 
VRF.inet.0 inet.0 ]`

Obviously this solution has a few drawbacks, but it is probably the simplest way.

Another solution would be to configure logical-tunnel interfaces between your VRF and inet.0 on the near-end PE, form an adjacency and export the route via BGP.